# Wifi and network management

Tags: wireless, kernel, internet, software-recommendation

I'm looking for software [on **Ubuntu**] to manage devices that connect to my **router** network *(through my laptop)* to connect/disconnect them, manage their session, schedule times, track their activities, etc.

Can I find a similar one anywhere, Please?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator

Comment: What do you mean by "that connect to my router network (through my laptop)"?

Comment: @Pilot6 I wanna manage devices that use my wifi (from my router) using my laptop...